# Get raw HTML output from WordPress REST API

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, rest

I'm using the [WordPress REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) to get the HTML content of my WordPress page in an external application. I'm calling this mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/10 and it returns:

```
"content": {
  "rendered": "[vc_column_text]Hello World[/vc_column_text]"
}
```

Is there any way to return the code in it's final HTML output and without the [vc_] shortcodes, eg: `<p>Hello World</p>`

The shortcodes are coming from the [Visual Composer page builder plugin](https://vc.wpbakery.com/).

Comment: Having the same issue here. I've been trying to use a content filter to transform it to HTML. I posted on the support forum as well, so I hope to get a response either there or here. :)  [WP REST API support forum post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/convert-shortcodes-to-html-for-json-api)

Answer (score 3):

Found and answer here: https://github.com/CompassHB/web/issues/67#issuecomment-245857301

The example below is taken from the link above:

```
/**
 * Modify REST API content for pages to force
 * shortcodes to render since Visual Composer does not
 * do this
 */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ()
{
   register_rest_field(
          'page',
          'content',
          array(
                 'get_callback'    => 'compasshb_do_shortcodes',
                 'update_callback' => null,
                 'schema'          => null,
          )
       );
});

function compasshb_do_shortcodes( $object, $field_name, $request )
{
   WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes(); // This does all the work

   global $post;
   $post = get_post ($object['id']);
   $output['rendered'] = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );

   // EDIT: add custom CSS to $output:
   $output[ 'yb_wpb_post_custom_css' ] = get_post_meta( $object[ 'id' ], '_wpb_post_custom_css', true);

   return $output;
}
```

## EDIT

A question arose in a comment: **how to get the custom CSS set for a page (post, etc.)?** I modified the sample code in a way that **it adds the custom CSS to the REST API response**. You'll find the CSS in `content/yb_wpb_post_custom_css`.

The other way is to add another field to the REST API response that contains this CSS. The key is that the custom CSS set for a page/post/etc. has a meta key **_wpb_post_custom_css**.

Comment: how do i get the CSS, rest api does not have CSS from Visual Composer ?

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis: I modified my answer so it now gives you a REST response with the custom CSS in it. **WPB** stores the custom CSS in a **meta**, not in the content, that's why you didn't get it with the request for content. **meta** can be added one-by-one, though - that's what I did.

Comment: `$output['rendered'] = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content());
`
thanks for the answer, i am retrieving page content from above line but now i want page CSS too in the api not the custom CSS. How do i Do it ? TIA

Comment: It's in the **EDIT** section of the answer - add a new field to **content**, or add a new field to the REST response.

Comment: I am not using custom CSS but expecting visual composer element CSS to be available in the API.
@muka.gergely

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis Sorry, but that makes no sense to me. You either set custom CSS (with the little icon above the content), or you have the element CSS in a **.css** file. Base styling of components is in a separate CSS, you won't get it through REST API (or you write an API function that serves that to you).

Comment: In the **rendered** content you only have CSS classes and IDs, but not the actual CSS styling of those classes and IDs - you need to locate the files that contain that, and download them to the frontend. (Of course, **style** set on an element is in the **rendered** content.)

Answer (score 1):

About 2 years late to the party, however, the following worked for me:

```
$output['rendered'] = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
```

Just in case if anyone was wondering.

Comment: How was this supposed to work for you? Did you add some filter? It's not clear.

Comment: I didn't add any filters, I was just getting the text from db and trying to get raw html without the shortcodes...